# Convolution of functions and measures

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, convolution

I need some help with this exercise. I'm not sure how to deal with it:

Let $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure in $[0,1]$ and $\nu$ the Lebesgue measure in $[2,\infty)$.

I have to find the convolutions $f\ast f$, $\mu\ast f$ and $\mu\ast\nu$.

Using the definition I don't get much, so I was wondering if there is a best way to compute them.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Using the definition, you get an integral that you simply need to compute. (Not trying to be unhelpful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, we have

$$\begin{align*} (f \ast f)(x) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y) \cdot f(y) \, dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left(-(x-y)^2 - y^2 \right) \, dy \\ &= \sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2} e^{-x^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp(2xy) \cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \exp \left( - \frac{y^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)}_{=:p(y)} \, dy. \end{align*}$$

for $\sigma^2 := 1/4$. As $y \mapsto p(y)$ is the density of the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2=1/4$, the integral can be computed using the widely known [formula for exponential moments of the normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions). Thus,

$$(f \ast f)(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-x^2} \cdot e^{\frac{1}{2} x^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2}$$

Alternatively, a more *probabilistic* reasoning can be used; it is based on the fact that the convolution of two distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$ equals the distribution of the random variable $X+Y$ where $X \sim \mu$, $Y \sim \nu$ are independent random variables. As $f$ is basically the density of a Gaussian random variable, the calculation of the convolution is pretty easy using some known properties of the Gaussian distribution.

---

Similarly, we find by the definition of the convolution that the measure $(\mu \ast \nu)$ has the density

$$\begin{align*} h(x)  &= \int 1_{[0,1]}(y) \cdot 1_{[2,\infty)}(x-y) \, dy \\ &= \int_0^1 1_{(-\infty,x-2]}(y) \, dy =  \begin{cases} 0 & x \leq 2 \\ x-2 & x  \in [2,3] \\ 1 & x \geq 3 \end{cases} \end{align*}$$

Comment: Excellent answer, saz! Thanks a lot!